# Fail to get bootstrap index from server - Read timed out - SonarQube Scanner

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I use SonarQube to validate and ensure code quality of my Ionic 3 mobile Application. I use MAC for development and I use local instance of SonarQube in MAC.

The version of SonarQube I use is 7.3 and the SonarQube Scanner is 3.2. As per the documentation, I ran the sonar.sh and got to see SonarQube server started successfully. I can navigate to `http://localhost:9000/about` to see the SonarQube page.

Created a file named sonar-project in the project root folder and provided the below informations in it.

```
# must be unique in a given SonarQube instance
sonar.projectKey= com.domain.app
# this is the name and version displayed in the SonarQube UI. Was mandatory prior to SonarQube 6.1.
sonar.projectName= 'myApp'
sonar.projectVersion= '0.0.1'

# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Replace "\" by "/" on Windows.
# This property is optional if sonar.modules is set. 
sonar.sources= './'

# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
#sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Also edited `/Users/ustuser/Documents/Softwares/sonar-scanner-3.2.0.1227-macosx/conf/sonar-scanner.properties` file to have the below properties.

```
#----- Default SonarQube server
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000

#----- Default source code encoding
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.java.source=1.8


# Language
sonar.language=ts
```

Navigated to `http://localhost:9000/` and loged-in ad admin. Generated a pass key by providing my project unique key. With all information, created a `.command` file. Below is the detail

```
sonar-scanner \
  -Dsonar.projectKey=com.domain.app \
  -Dsonar.sources=.\
  -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 \
  -Dsonar.login=xxxx69c0bc10ba1b78xxxx2c2c1d305c7cfxxxx
```

On running the command file from the project root directory, I am getting below error.

```
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.2.0.1227
INFO: Java 1.8.0_121 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64
INFO: User cache: /Users/ustuser/.sonar/cache
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 1:00.388s
INFO: Final Memory: 4M/123M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute SonarQube
ERROR: Caused by: Fail to get bootstrap index from server
ERROR: Caused by: timeout
ERROR: Caused by: Read timed out
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging
```

I could find only limited information working with standalone SonarQube Scanner in internet.

On running with -X switch, I got the below error.

```
                                                                                                         10:29:30.729 DEBUG: Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
10:29:30.743 DEBUG: Get bootstrap index...
10:29:30.743 DEBUG: Download: http://localhost:9000/batch/index
10:30:30.872 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:30:30.872 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
10:30:30.872 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:30:30.873 INFO: Total time: 1:00.621s
10:30:30.905 INFO: Final Memory: 4M/123M
10:30:30.905 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:30:30.905 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarQube
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:85)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:74)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:70)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:167)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:113)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:73)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to get bootstrap index from server
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:42)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.getScannerEngineFiles(JarDownloader.java:58)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:53)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:76)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.Okio$4.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:230)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:285)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:241)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:46)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http1.Http1Codec$UnknownLengthSource.read(Http1Codec.java:482)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.RealBufferedSource.request(RealBufferedSource.java:67)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals(RealBufferedSource.java:408)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals(RealBufferedSource.java:392)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.Util.bomAwareCharset(Util.java:431)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:174)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:99)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:39)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:139)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Did you check the 'Execute Analysis' rights? Also run using the -X switch and see if that prints more relevant information.

Comment: Thanks. I have 'Execute Analysis' rights. But on running with -X switch, I got more logs. I have edited my question with the logs. Any comment would help in moving.

Comment: Do you use anti-virus software on this server or do you have a proxy installed between the scanner and the SonarQube server? Increase the timeout setting (sonar.ws.timeout) to check if that helps.

Comment: sonar.ws.timeout didn't helped. I am behind a proxy network. But trying to understand how it will affect. My SonarQube server is running in my local machine as well my source code is in my local. Where the proxy role will be in this case.

Comment: If everything is local then the proxy should not make a difference. Maybe you can move the whole setup to another (non company) PC.